# .NET Core 1.1.0 publish: is node_modules folder mandatory?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, webpack, .net-core, publishing, node-modules

I've published a new web app on ASPHostPortal hosting service from Visual Studio 2015 and through an FTP publish profile.
All works fine but during the publishing, in particular during *node_modules* folder upload, it's taken very very very long time to finish.
I'm using webpack so, for future publishes, I'm wondering: is the *node_modules* folder upload mandatory?
Can I exclude that from publish?

Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node_modules` are not needed for your app that is bundled with webpack and you can and should exclude them when publishing it.

Webpack creates a bundle that is self-contained (or split among multiple bundles), that means that all dependencies of your app are inside the bundle(s) unless you configured [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), which requires those dependencies to be available at runtime. But since this is a web app these would have to be included in a script tag and that's unlikely to come from `node_modules`.

To go a step further, it's enough to only publish the files created by webpack (talking strictly about the JavaScript part of your app) which will usually be in a separate directory (e.g. `dist/`). Of course you need to have some HTML to include the bundle(s), which could also be generated by webpack.